# Placing multiple markers in google maps using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add multiple markers in Google map using ajax, javascript and php. There is no error but the markers are not showing why? Please help. Please see the sample output of AJAX DATA below:

> Array(3409)
>   [0 … 99]
>   0
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.901177,120.867704"}
>   1
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.620365,120.577517"}
>   2
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.869043,120.463918"}
>   3
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.436324,120.487099"}
>   4
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.676802,120.535833"}
>   5
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.564611,120.595372"}
>   6
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.720815,120.535681"}
>   7
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.867589,120.463541"}
>   8
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.680134,120.539518"}
>   9
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.867287,120.464906"}
>   10
>   :
>   {GPS_COORDINATES: "14.840842,120.475522"}

[SCREENSHOT OF AJAX DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnR9R.png)

Here is my AJAX code:

```
function initMap() {

  var map;

  $.ajax({
    url: "retailer-marker.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      search: search,
      coordinator: coordinator
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

      var center = new google.maps.LatLng(12.5, 122);
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5.2,
        center: center
      });
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i][0]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: position,
          map: map,
          title: data[i][0]
        });
      }

    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
    $sql = "SELECT GPS_COORDINATES FROM ret_retailer";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
} 

print json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` array contains objects. So `data[i][0]` will not work. You would need `data[i].GPS_COORDINATES`.

<del>So, the following should work:</del>

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].GPS_COORDINATES);
```

If you simply had done a `console.log(data[i])`, that would have been quite obvious.

**Edit**:

It's the way you create the `LatLng` object that causes an issue. The `LatLng` method expects 2 arguments (lat and lng) and you are passing only one (as a string containing both lat and lng). This works for me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  var coords = data[i].GPS_COORDINATES.split(','); // Split your string on the coma to get lat and lng as separate values
  var position = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]); // Use them here as LatLng method expects 2 arguments

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    title: 'hello'
  });
}
```

Also as a side note, make sure you declare your variables properly (with the use of `var` keyword), for example: `var i = 0;` and `var marker = ...` and so on.

Comment: @MaricrisPacheco Mark it as correct answer to the question if it solved your issue

Comment: Its not there is still no markers being displayed @MarcelDjaman

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i know that tutorial how can I convert my **AJAX data** into the format of var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

Comment: While this might work, please explain why it would solve OP's question. Just copy-pasting a code snippet from the documentation doesn't help anyone.